# Configure mockito to print actual argument values in verification error messages

Tags: java, logging, mockito

When describing failed verification, by default Mockito prints only call sites where interactions happened. Like this:

```
    Wanted but not invoked:
    proxyListener.foundTemplateParam(
        "fooBar2",
        isNull(),
        isNull()
    );
    -> at        foo.ProxyHandlerTest.testThatImplicitParamsScannedCorrectly(ProxyHandlerTest.java:136)

    However, there were other interactions with this mock:
    -> at foo.ProxyHandler.<init>(ProxyHandler.java:99)
    -> at foo.ProxyHandler.<init>        (ProxyHandler.java:100)
    -> at foo.ProxyHandler.scanForParamSetters(ProxyHandler.java:222)
    -> at foo.ProxyHandler.<init>(ProxyHandler.java:102)
    -> at foo.ProxyHandler.<init>(ProxyHandler.java:104)
```

That's useful information but I would also like to see what arguments where passed during those interactions. Is there a way to achieve this?

P. S. I know about mocking with `withSettings().verboseLogging()`. But it's too verbose and is printed to stdout instead of adding this info to assertion error message.

**Update**:
Mockito 1.9.0 doesn't support customization of exception error messages out of the box (I just checked their sources).

Comment: Can you just run your test with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

the safest place to do that is an answer that prints arguments and return the given value.

You could then write something like :

```
given(some.callWith(arg1, arg2)).will(printArgsAndReturn("some value"));
```

where `printArgsAndReturn("some value")` actually returns your custom answer.

Comment: That's a good one if you need to target specific method's arguments. But if I wanted to print all invocation arguments without changing much code I'd go with mocking `withSettings().invocationListeners(...my pretty printer listener...)`. That's how they do `verboseLogging()` anyway.